# How do you create a variadic function that doesn't need the caller to pass arguments count to it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

EDIT: I am pleased to see that there is a solution for C++11. Regardless, no one has yet come up with an answer for C++98. So, even though I've accepted an answer, the question still stands.

Let us assume you have a function within a namespace:

```
namespace Math
{
  int Sum(<params>);
}
```

How do you implement this function Math::Sum such that the caller can call it with any number of arguments yet the caller doesn't need to pass the number of arguments too.
The caller also needs to still have to fully qualify it at the call site. Example:
`Math::Sum(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)`

Comment: Macros? Varargs? eurgh, no thanks

Comment: well, sometimes, even on the newest of compilers you need a bit of macro magic to bend them to your will ;) 
Especially when they're not fully C++11 compliant :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one generic way that works, in C++11, with any type supporting the additive operator (`operator +`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T, typename U>
auto Sum(T&& t, U&& u) -> decltype(t + u)
{
    return (t + u);
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
auto Sum(T&& t, Ts&&... ts) -> decltype(
    t + Sum(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
    )
{
    return t + Sum(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Sum(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Sum(1.0, 2.0, 3.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Sum(std::string("Hello "), std::string("World!")) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. One observation is that it only works for compilers with variadic template support. Nonetheless, it has the added benefit of supporting multiple types I believe.

Comment: @Zadirion: True. I thought that was acceptable to you because you tagged the question as "C++11"

Answer (score 5):

The approach used by `std::min` and `std::max` in C++11 is to take an `initializer_list`

```
int Sum(std::initializer_list<int>);
```

This is suitable when all the arguments should be the same type. You would call it as `Sum({ 1, 2, 3, 4})`

Comment: Interesting. Since I needed my solution on VS2010 when I did the research, I forgot about the upcoming initializer lists feature. Indeed that's the C++11 way, thank you for your contribution!